# Error Start workflow via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I can't get start a Workflow via Web Script.

I created the file workflow.get.js:

```
var nodeId = args.nodeid; //fdadc86f-d996-472d-8267-850a63573b02
var workflowName = args.w; //jbpm$wf:adhoc
var document = search.findNode("workspace://SpacesStore/" + nodeId); 
var workflowAction = actions.create("start-workflow"); 
workflowAction.parameters.workflowName = workflowName; 
workflowAction.parameters["bpm:workflowDescription"] = "Please edit: " + document.name; 
workflowAction.parameters["bpm:assignees"] = [people.getPerson("admin"), people.getPerson("admin")];
var futureDate = new Date(); 
futureDate.setDate(futureDate.getDate() + 7); 
workflowAction.parameters["bpm:workflowDueDate"] = futureDate; 
workflowAction.execute(document);
```

workflow.get.desc.xml

```
  <webscript>

  <shortname>Start Workflow</shortname>

  <description>Testando Start Workflow</description>

  <url>/workflow?nodeid={idfile}&amp;&amp;w={namewf}</url>

  <format default="html">argument</format>

  <authentication>admin</authentication>

  <transaction>required</transaction>

</webscript>
```

and workflow.get.html.ftl

```
The ${args.w} started!
```

when I click http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/workflow?nodeId=fdadc86f-d996-472d-8267-850a63573b02&w=jbpm$wf:adhoc return the error

> 06190076 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 06190474 Failed to execute script '/triggerworkflow.get.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts)': 06190473 Can't find method org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptAction.execute(org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined). (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts)#11)
>
> Exception: org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException - 08200041 TypeError: Cannot read property "name" from null 
>   (workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions/Workflow/workflow.get.js#7)
>
> org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:469)
>
> Exception: org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException - 08200042 Failed to execute script '/Workflow/workflow.get.js 
>   (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions)': 08200041 TypeError: Cannot read 
>   property "name" from null (workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions/Workflow/workflow.get.js#7)
>
> org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:183)
>
> Exception: org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException - 08200035 Wrapped Exception (with status template):
>   08200042 Failed to execute script '/Workflow/workflow.get.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions)'
>   : 08200041 TypeError: Cannot read property "name" from null (workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions/Workflow/
>   workflow.get.js#7)
>
> org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:742) 
>   Anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're calling arguments one thing in one place, and a different thing in another:

```
var nodeId = args.nodeid; //fdadc86f-d996-472d-8267-850a63573b02
var workflowName = args.w; //jbpm$wf:adhoc
```

vs

```
<url>/workflow?nodeid={idfile}&amp;&amp;w={namewf}</url>
```

You need to get those to agree! I'd suggest, given the URL you seem to already be using from the client, changing your webscript descriptor URL to match what you use, to:

```
<url>/workflow?nodeid={nodeid}&amp;w={w}</url>
```

You should also add logic to check that the node given really exists - [`search.findNode` can return null](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/jscript/Search.html#findNode-org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef-) so you should check that before continuing (eg and give a 404 if not found)

Also, you could use [`utils.getNodeFromString(String)`](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/jscript/ScriptUtils.html#getNodeFromString-java.lang.String-) if you'd rather

Comment: could you explain me if use 
**workflow.get.js**
var workflow = actions.create("start-workflow");
workflow.parameters.workflowName = "activiti$TrainerEmpanelment";
workflow.parameters["bpm:assignee"] = people.getPerson("admin");
workflow.parameters["initiator"] = people.getPerson("admin"); 
var today = new Date();
var duedate = today.getDate() + 1; 
workflow.parameters["bpm:workflowDueDate"] = duedate;
workflow.execute(document);

what will be the url of  workflow.get.desc.xml file

Comment: You probably don't want the URL of the `.desc.xml` file - that's normally only needed when browsing the list of available webscripts. If you want the URL to call the webscript, then that's whatever you put in the `<url>` tag in the descriptions file! If this is all too much, I'd suggest you either buy a copy of "Professional Alfresco" (a few years old but the webscript stuff is still the same), or go on an Alfresco training course

Comment: I have changed url in` .desc.xml file`  save it and goto alfresco webscripts referesh it click webscript i am getting error > "06190085 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 06190498 Failed to execute script '/triggerworkflow.get.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts)': missing ; before statement (/triggerworkflow.get.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts)#6)"

Comment: That error message is quite clear to me - you have a syntax in your JavaScript file! Seriously though, I think at this point you need to get yourself on an Alfresco training course - you appear to be missing too many fundamental things for random strangers on the internet to be able to help

Comment: I fixed the issue now i getting error **06190086 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 06190502 Failed to execute script '/triggerworkflow.get.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts)': 06190501 ReferenceError: "document" is not defined. (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts)#11)**""

Answer (score 0):

Please try to start your workflow using this code,
replace your code of `workflow.get.js` with this code and change all the properties according to your requirement.

```
function startWorkflow()
{
    var workflowAction = workflow.getDefinitionByName("activiti$test_wf");
    var package= workflow.createPackage();

    var wfparams = new Array();
    wfparams["model_prefix:req_props_name"] = value2;

    wfparams["bpm:assignee"] = people.getPerson("ADMIN");
    workflowAction.startWorkflow(package, wfparams);
    }

}

startWorkflow();
```